# Hive ParseException: cannot recognize input near 'create' 'table'

Tags: hiveql

I am trying to conduct a hive query of the form

```
with (
select a,b from some_db.some_table
) as my_subquery

create table some_other_db.new_table as select * from my_subquery
```

And I am getting the error

```
cannot recognize input near 'create' 'table' 'some_other_db' in statement
```

How do I resolve?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in hive you cannot include `create` statements after a `with` statement. They need to be before.

The following query worked:

```
create table some_other_db.new_table as 
with (
select a,b from some_db.some_table
) as my_subquery

select * from my_subquery
```